# Selenium grid implementation issue- Not able to run Parallel Browsers

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

This is my below testing XML file code:Please look this testNG file

```
  <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
   <suite name="parallel tests" parallel="tests">
    <test name="IETest1">
        <parameter name="platform" value="Windows" />
        <parameter name="browser" value="InternetExplorer" />
        <parameter name="runmode" value="Local" />
        <classes>
            <class name="in.zest.MiTest.MiCreditTests"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="ChromeTest1">
        <parameter name="platform" value="Windows" />
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
        <parameter name="runmode" value="Local" />

        <classes>
            <class name="in.zest.MiTest.MiCreditTests" />
        </classes>
       </test>
 </suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

**Test:**

```
@Parameters({ "platform","browser", "runmode" })
@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod(String platform, String browser, String runmode) `enter code here`throws MalformedURLException {
    report = Common.getExtentReport();
    test = report.startTest("MICreditTests");
    //driver = BrowserFactory.getBrowser(runmode, browser);
    RestAssured.baseURI = "https://zestmoney2.sandbox.mambu.com";

    DesiredCapabilities caps=new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);

    if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("InternetExplorer"))
    {
        caps=DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        String hubURL="http://192.168.0.3:4447/wd/hub";
         driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubURL),caps);
    }
    if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
    {

        caps.setBrowserName(browser);
        //ChromeOptions defined
        ChromeOptions options=new ChromeOptions();
        options.merge(caps);
        String hubURL="http://192.168.0.3:4458/wd/hub";
         driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubURL), options);

    }

     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```

This is the script for setup: where i have registered two nodes on 
      Hub.one node for Internet Explorer and 2nd for Chrome browser. when i am 
      trying to execute. first it is completing Execution on 
      IE then Chrome browser is getting started. Please help me out what code i 
      need to update to run both browser parallel.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in your xml file. Add **parallel test structure** and **thread count** to run parallel tests. below xml works fine for me. Note: there is a small time gap because of driver load time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Login Related Tests" parallel="tests" thread-count="4">
    <test name="Chrome login Test"  parallel="tests" preserve-order="true" group-by-instances="false" >
        <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome" />
        <parameter name="URL" value="AdminURL"/>
        <parameter name="Env" value="QA"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.Login"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Firefox Login Test" parallel="tests" preserve-order="true" group-by-instances="false" >
        <parameter name="browser" value="Firefox" />
        <parameter name="URL" value="AdminURL"/>
        <parameter name="Env" value="QA"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.Login"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your testng.xml is missing 'thread-count' parameter . Change it as below

```
<suite name="parallel tests" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
```